# English equivalent of Russian "понаберут по объявлению"

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms, translation, russian

In Russian, there's an idiom "понаберут по объявлению".

Directly it can be translated as "[they] recruit by ads".

The intention behind this idiom is to derogate the one who was "recruited", implying that the "ads" recruitment attracts mostly low-quality candidates, hence the one who was "recruited" has insufficient skills for the position.

This saying can be used when the process was not ad-based at all.
For instance, the case when a person [destroyed](https://www.reddit.com/r/cscareerquestions/comments/6ez8ag/accidentally_destroyed_production_database_on/) a database on their first day of work could have the following dialogue between coworkers:

> - Привет Вить! Что вчера случилось?
> - Да стажёр вчера главную базу удалил.
> - Мда ... понаберут по объявлению...

which roughly translates as

> - Hi Victor! What happened yesterday?
> - A trainee deleted the main database.
> - Holy ... recruit by ads...

Is there an English equivalent of the given Russian idiom?

Comment: As is often the case with idioms, the literal translation is not an existing English idiom. But there are plenty of colorful ways to say someone is underskilled for their position...

Comment: None come to mind, at the moment; in my native language we have an expression which roughly translates into "that's what they (the company) get for letting everyone in". I would use the same when speaking English, to be honest.

Comment: I have heard people say "Agency staff!" though it's not an idiom.